# how to edit image using php

Tags: php, image-processing

I have written following set of codes.

```
$image = ImageCreate(200, 50);
$background_color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // white
$gray = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204); // gray
ImageFilledRectangle($image, 50, 10, 150, 40, $gray);
header('Content-type: image/png');
ImagePNG($image);
```

while running this code I get an error

```
The image "http://localhost/app/" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

Please help me.

Comment: `Running this code` from terminal/command-line or in a browser?

Comment: @back in a flash: Running in a browser

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: @BackinaFlash: Have u used the same code.

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly a `PHP` error, because the code you posted is correct. This is mostlikely caused by some extra data outside the `php tags.`

if this is all you have in the file it works

```
<?php
$image = ImageCreate(200, 50);
$background_color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // white
$gray = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204); // gray
ImageFilledRectangle($image, 50, 10, 150, 40, $gray);
header('Content-type: image/png');
ImagePNG($image);
?>
```

but this wont

```
<?php
//see the new line outside the php tags below? this will break the image.
?>

<?php
$image = ImageCreate(200, 50);
$background_color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // white
$gray = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204); // gray
ImageFilledRectangle($image, 50, 10, 150, 40, $gray);
header('Content-type: image/png');
ImagePNG($image);



//these extra lines wont matter, because they are inside the php tags.


?>
```

Make sure you have no extra spaces or newlines before `<?php`. If you have an include file before this code, also check that file (files) to make sure there is no data outside `<?php ?>`